# Calling serial_port::cancel causes Run-Time Check Failure #0 on Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, serial-port, boost-asio

This is a fatal error, there's no way to recover from it, and in release builds, a nasty message box appears. It happens when I call serial_port::cancel and Boost tries to throw some exception. The exact error is:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>   across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a
>   function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer
>   declared with a different calling convention.

And it seems to happen in throw_error.ipp, inside the do_throw_error method.
Here's a small sample program which reproduces this:

```
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/read.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

BYTE g_pBuffer[128];

void ReadCompletionHandler( boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytesTransferred ){
    if( !ec ){
        cout << "Read " << bytesTransferred << " bytes successfully" << endl;
    }else if( ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted ){
        cout << "Aborted async_read_some, " << bytesTransferred << " bytes transferred" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Read finished with errors: " << ec.message() << endl;
    }
}

void ReaderThread( boost::asio::serial_port* pSerialPort ){
    cout << "[ReaderThread] Started reading" << endl;
    boost::asio::async_read( *pSerialPort, boost::asio::buffer( g_pBuffer, 5 ), ReadCompletionHandler );
    cout << "[ReaderThread] Done!" << endl;
}

void main(){
    //Tell cout not to buffer its output so output better reflects multithreaded execution
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::unitbuf);
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::asio::serial_port serialPort( ioService );
    string portName = "COM1";
    serialPort.open( portName );
    if( !serialPort.is_open() ){
        cout << "Failed to open " << portName << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "Launching reader thread and io_service" << endl;
    boost::thread readerThread( boost::bind( ReaderThread, &serialPort ) );
    ioService.run();
    cout << "Sleeping..." << endl;
    ::Sleep( 5000 );
    cout << "Woke up, cancelling pending reads" << endl;
    serialPort.cancel();
    cout << "Waiting for reader thread to finish..." << endl;
    readerThread.join();
    cout << "Done!" << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

Maybe I'm doing something stupid. What do you think?

Comment: AFAIK, completion handlers require the _stdcall calling convention.

Comment: Adding __stdcall to `ReadCompletionHandler`'s definition didn't solve it. If I change the project's calling convention to __stdcall, it stops building. So it seems Boost was built with the __cdecl convention. Should I rebuild Boost so that it uses __stdcall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows XP, `serial_port::cancel` calls [CancelIo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which cancels pending I/O for the **calling** thread. So the solution is dispatching the call to the thread where `io_service::run` is running:

```
ioService.post( [&]{serialPort.cancel();} );
```

Thanks a lot to the guys at the boost-users list (Igor R and Richard Rowlands).
Anyway, I believe Boost should check that the calling thread is the serial port's owner, I mean, cancel is not an operation you'll call intensively.